# How to pull image using HELM without URL

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a method to configure `Docker` or `Kubernetes` to pull image into a created `container` without specifying the `URL` of the private registry in the `HELM-charts` which shall include only the `image` name and its `tag` ?!

In other words:

Instead of setting the image's URL in the `value.yaml` or `Deployment.yaml` files, instruct docker (or helm) to go pull the image directly from the private registry !

Comment: I guess in theory you could do it with a mutating admission controller, but if Helm is involved, it's much clearer and fairly standard to include a `registry:` setting in the `values.yaml` file, and construct `image: {{ .Values.registry }}/{{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.tag }}`.

Comment: @DavidMaze . This is what I am currently implementing. But I wondering how to direct docker or helm to skip docker hub and go to the private registry in a configuration file ! where is this config file and what do I have to change !!

Comment: For pure Docker, there is a setting to point at an alternate Docker Hub mirror, but in general it's discouraged; you don't want to accidentally run `malware.example.com/library/mysql` when you `docker run mysql`.  There are more details in the linked question.

Comment: @DavidMaze . Well, you got me convinced by the security point of pulling a malware. But I am testing it over a secure network (with no access to internet) and my HELM-Charts package doesn't have any dependencies to 3rd party images. Thank a lot though for pointing to the hub mirroring solution. Will check it out.